# How can I lock a sliding door that doesn't have a door lock?

Tags: lock

I don't know if this question constitutes a home improvement or life hack but I'll ask here first. We live downstairs for my wife's parents in Japan. My wife's mother occasional invades downstairs. She changes around things- this infuriates my somewhat control-freak wife. Is there a device that I buy on the internet that allow a sliding door to be locked? Its a double sliding door with no internals of Japanese design- more robust that those paper doors but essential light weight wood on the wood runner with no bearings. I need non-permanent- no modifications to either door or wall. Just need to provide some resistance to entry. Its an internal door. Because there are two sliding doors- I envision perhaps a Z connection- A L with an end- the gap between the doors is 5mm- and small lock to lock the doors together. Have you seen something like that? We have a decent a hardware store at last near home but no tools.

Comment: Will YOU or your wife need to unlock this door from the outside when you get home to get in?

Comment: A quick and easy "lock" is a length of wood or broom handle placed in the tracks that prevents the doors from sliding open. That was always our "back up" lock in our sliding exterior door since our primary was flimsy.

Comment: There are a number of commercial products for this purpose; websearch should find them easily, or a locksmith can recommend solutions. For your problem that broom handle is probably plenty. Seriously securing a sliding patio door (at least the type common in the US) takes more work; ideally I'd replace it if you were concerned about burglary.

Comment: You should leave little traps for her like upside down chair mats and cups of water attached to tripwires.

Comment: Also, are you sure this lock won't cause more problems? Maybe this is a question for SE.Interpersonal :p

Answer (score 1):

You can cut a stick to lay in the track where the door slides, that's an old trick.  You can also drill a vertical hole in the track, say an inch deep, and drop a 2" nail in there, to block the door from sliding open, similar idea.

They make little clamp on sliding window locks

[image: http://img0068.psstatic.com/106582615_amazoncom-sliding-window-lock-aluminum-finish-home-.jpg]

that might work.

Answer (score 0):

The Z would do it & you might find just the top portion of an over door hanger would work, [there are several here](http://www.walmart.com/c/kp/over-the-door-hooks)

Other than that, you might try L-brackets tied together will do the trick. [These are perfect for a wing-nut screw together & your hardware store might customize them](http://www.walmart.com/ip/2-Pieces-Silver-Tone-L-Shaped-Corner-Angle-Bracket-Shelf-150mm-x-100mm/48511677)

Just wrap the contact points with a rubberized tape to avoid door marks.

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming you want the door to be locked from the outside and when you are not home?  Here are some items that should have the type and style you would find appropriate for your home: [keyed sliding door handles .](http://www.ebay.com/sch/i.html?_odkw=sliding%20door%20lock&_osacat=0&_from=R40&_trksid=p2045573.m570.l1313.TR1.TRC0.A0.H0.Xkeyed%20sliding%20door%20lock.TRS0&_nkw=keyed%20sliding%20door%20lock&_sacat=0)